# Mongo aggregate match + group with sum - return 0 if no matches

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

See [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Kxhuz-ZsN7G). Here's the query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      time: {
        $gte: 20,
        $lte: 40
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      amount: {
        $sum: "$amount"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      amount: 1
    }
  }
])
```

If no match found, it just returns an empty array. I would like it to return `[{amount: 0}]` even if no match. How is it possible?

Comment: Don't use the match query, apply `$cond` instead in `$sum`. By applying the conditions in the match query, you are restricting those documents to the next stage. Let me know want code same

Comment: Yes, could you please show an example?

Comment: Added an answer, see if that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `$match` pipeline and and add `$cond` inside `$sum` to process all the records.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      amount: {
        $sum: {
          "$cond": {
            "if": {
              "$and": [
                {
                  "$gte": [
                    "$amount",
                    20
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "$lte": [
                    "$amount",
                    40
                  ]
                },
              ]
            },
            "then": "$amount",
            "else": 0,
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      amount: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground Sample Execution](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sN9zg-jo3Sz)